# Scrapy - Load a yaml file with a relative path inside the spider

Tags: python, scrapy, yaml, scrapyd

I'm trying to deploy my `scrapy crawlers`, but the problem is that I have a `yaml file` that I'm trying to load from inside the `spider`,
this works when the spider is loaded from the shell: `scrapy crawl <spider-name>`.
But when the spider is deployed inside `scrapyd`, the path to the yaml file must be `absolute`.

Is there a way to use a `relative path` for the `yaml file`, even when spiders are deployed with `scrapyd`?

**P.S**:
The `spider` is deployed on `scrapyd` with:

```
scrapyd-deploy default -p <project-name>
curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/schedule.json -d project=<project-name> -d spider=<spider-name>
```

And the `yaml` file is loaded with:

```py
with open('../categories/categories.yaml', 'r') as f:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer here: [scrapyd and **file** (pkgutil.get_data)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapy-users/B70eq1_N3Fk/vR7aDeizj_sJ)

Briefly, you have to add register paths to these `static files` in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths are relative to the current working directory (the directory where your script was started from). If you want to load a file from a path relative to the current script location you can try the following:

```
root_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
yaml_path = os.path.join(root_dir, '../categories/categories.yaml')
with open(yaml_path, 'r') as f:
    pass
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesnt work. Scrapy & scrapyd have a special way of loading files (**see my answer above**).